# Check if a socket is already opened - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-functions

**Problem:**
I have an Azure timer function which runs every minute to trigger a socket which gets data from a website. I don't want to establish a connection everytime the timer runs the function.

**Question:** Is there a way in Python which I can check if a socket is open for a particular website on particular port?
Or, is there a way to re-use a socket in time-triggered applications?

This entire process runs every minute:

```py
# Open socket
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(20)  # 20 sec timeout

    if is_socket_open(sock):
        logging.info("Socket is already open")
    else:
        logging.info("No socket was open. Opening a new one...")
        sock.connect(server_address)
        sock.settimeout(None)

    logging.info(f"Connected to {sock}")
    return sock

except socket.gaierror as e:
    logging.exception(f"Error connecting to remote server {e}")
    time.sleep(20)
except socket.error as e:
    logging.exception(f"Connection error {e}")
    time.sleep(20)
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(f"An exception occurred: {e}")
    time.sleep(20)

def is_socket_open(sock: socket.socket) -> bool:
try:
    # this will try to read bytes without blocking and also without removing them from buffer (peek only)
    data = sock.recv(16, socket.MSG_PEEK)
    if len(data) == 0:
        return True
except socket.timeout:
    return False  # socket is not connected yet, therefore receiving timed out
except BlockingIOError:
    return False  # socket is open and reading from it would block
except ConnectionResetError:
    return True  # socket was closed for some other reason
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(f"unexpected exception when checking if a socket is closed: {e}")
    return False
return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use global variables to reuse objects in future invocations. The following example was copied from [Google Cloud Platform documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#functions-tips-scopes-python), but you can apply the same concept to your Azure Function:

```py
# Global (instance-wide) scope
# This computation runs at instance cold-start
instance_var = heavy_computation()

def scope_demo(request):
    # Per-function scope
    # This computation runs every time this function is called
    function_var = light_computation()
    return 'Instance: {}; function: {}'.format(instance_var, function_var)
```

In your case, you can declare the `sock` as a global variable and reuse it in future **warm start invocations**. You should also increase the timeout to above 60 seconds, giving that you're triggering your azure function every minute.

However, keep in mind that there is no guarantee that the state of the function will be preserved for future invocations. For instance, in auto-scaling situations, a new socket would be open.

Microsoft Azure also says the following in regards to client connections:

> To avoid holding more connections than necessary, reuse client instances rather than creating new ones with each function invocation. We recommend reusing client connections for any language that you might write your function in.

### See also:

- [Manage connections in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#static-clients)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's exactly what I am trying to do actually. Reusing the socket so that I don't have to create/instantiate a new ones. I will have a look at your solution and try to see how it is done in Azure.

Comment: Awesome, hopefully it worked out for you at the end! If you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as 'Accepted', thank you! :)